# iOS Developer Program - Number of applications and limitation of devices

Tags: ios, app-store

1. With the iOS Developer Program can I development more than one application?
2. With the iOS Developer Program there is a limitation for 100 devices. 
   How this limitation works? Do I have to generate a certificate to test on with device? If I uninstall the application, will count?
3. For example: I have 15 devices to test applications and i created 10 applications. I want to test all application on all devices. In this case will count 15 devices or will count 150 devices?
4. I need to register all the devices on Apple’s site to test on device (correct me if I’m wrong). Do I need to do the registration for each application (that means 150 registrations) or just 15 (one for witch device)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can develop an unlimited number of applications.

You are limited to testing your applications on 100 specific devices. You submit the device identifiers to Apple's website and it gives you a provisioning profile (which you must install on each device) that allows your applications to run on those specific devices. You can add additional devices at any time (up to 100) but you can only remove devices and start over once a year.

The 100 device limit is per developer account, not per application.

Answers to edits:

1. It will count as only 15 devices.
2. You just need to register the 15 devices once.

Comment: If I Uninstall and Install the application over and over again on 1 device only, that will count as 1 device? Or for each install/uninstall of the app will count as 1?

Comment: @fr33d0om You can install/uninstall an unlimited number of times.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no limitations for number of applications in dev propgram. You can develop applications as much as you want. Limitation for devices works simple pretty forward - you can  test any developed application only for 100 devices.